# Excluding a field from a Bag after loading

Tags: apache-pig

A is the bag with original data and I ranked them.

```
A = LOAD '$input' USING PigStorage(',');
RA = rank A;
```

Need to exclude $3 from RA and store the resultant into hdfs.

This can be done while loading itself but I need them as 2 bags.
Original data and Temprorary data (after excluding $3 from Original data).

Answer (score 2):

After ranking, attempt this:

```
A1 = FOREACH RA GENERATE $0, $1, $2, $4 .. ;
A2 = FOREACH RA GENERATE $3;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vicsana. What if we dont know the lastfield.Is there an option to range that? start form $0,exclude$3,endup till Last$

Comment: Hey, I just found how to reference the last field. Check the updated answer. I hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thats great Vicsana.Ok I can use that. but still my question is there.If I am trying to exclude $2 it wont work:(.I am taking that as a param(which field to split)